# How to insert many rows data of table into DB?

Tags: java, database, rows

This is my code and i want two rows data into my database but when i proceed only last row or second rows data set into my database table :

```
try{

int rows=tblCO2.getRowCount();

 for(int row = 0; row<rows; row++)
  {
    System.out.println(row);
    String itemcode = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 0);
    String lotno = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 1);
    String stackno = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 2);
    String grade = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 3);
    String ctns = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 4);

    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/demo","user","pw");
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        String queryco = "Insert into alicreative.pur(itemcode,lotno,stackno,grade,ctns) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(queryco);
        pst.setString(1, itemcode);
        pst.setString(2, lotno);
        pst.setString(3, stackno);
        pst.setString(4, grade);
        pst.setString(5, ctns);
        pst.addBatch();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
    }


}
pst.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
}
catch(  HeadlessException | SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
}
```

So  tell me solution for save two rows of data in one action.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new Connection object for each row.  Why ?

(As a consequence, you'll also have as many distinct PreparedStatement objects as you have rows.  How many and which one will actually execute after the end of your loop ?)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `PreparedStatement` (and create your connection) before your loop, because as it is, you are creating a new one at each iteration, and populating it with one batch.

Finally you end up executing only the last `PreparedStatement` (which contains only the batch for the last row) .

```
try{

int rows=tblCO2.getRowCount();

Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/demo","user","pw");
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
String queryco = "Insert into alicreative.pur(itemcode,lotno,stackno,grade,ctns) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(queryco);

for(int row = 0; row<rows; row++)
{
    System.out.println(row);
    String itemcode = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 0);
    String lotno = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 1);
    String stackno = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 2);
    String grade = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 3);
    String ctns = (String)tblCO2.getValueAt(row, 4);

    try
    {

        pst.setString(1, itemcode);
        pst.setString(2, lotno);
        pst.setString(3, stackno);
        pst.setString(4, grade);
        pst.setString(5, ctns);
        pst.addBatch();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
    }


}
pst.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
}
catch(  HeadlessException | SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
}
```